# Can we use "the" with outer space?

Tags: grammaticality

Can we use "the" with outer space?

Which one is correct?

> 1. the outer space
> 2. outer space

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It's a reasonable question but it's difficult to give a properly supported answer because proving that "The Outer Space" is not used is really proving a negative. However putting "the outer space" into Google only returns hits for "outer space" of whch there are very many. Outer Space (meaning, as [space.com](https://www.space.com/24870-what-is-space.html) defines it)

> a zone that occurs about 100 kilometers (60 miles) above the planet, where there is no appreciable air to breathe or to scatter light

is a single region so large that we have no idea how big it is and incorporating many other regions such as nebulae, solar systems, planetary atmospheres, black holes and so on. It is always referred to, so far as I can tell, as "Outer Space" or, sometimes "Space".

Linguistically this is similar to treating the noun "Space" like the name of a city; no one calls New York "The New York" because New York is the name of a city and no other city has that name. We would say "The City of New York" but that is different.

"The outer space" sounds like the description of part of a building or a building and its environs. For instance the parts of an ancient temple might be described as

> "**The inner space**, or holy of holies, to which only the priests had access, and **the outer space** which was open to all the faithful.

Similarly an estate agent (realtor if you're American) might write

> "**The outer space** connected to this property consists of a well-presented enclosed patio area"

Space and Outer Space as proper nouns are not, normally used with the definite article.

Comment: Googling for `"the outer space"` (with quotes) shows only a movie by that name, a ballroom by that name, and "the outer space treaty".

Comment: @HotLicks The only movie I could find by looking googling "the outer space" was The Outer Space Connection. Did you find one called "The Outer Space"?

Comment: Apparently I misread the link -- it was a [live musical performance](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/08/theater/the-outer-space-review.html).